# Parsing PHP variables to Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

i have Bootstrap based website, and I want to use PHP GET variables in Tabs. I need to make pagination on each tab and use selected page in MySQL query.

So I need to make `my-website.com/site.php#tab1?page=2` work.

Is is possible?

I have now fixed the hrefs to tabs, but passing variables is not working for me.
Im using this JS

```
// Tabs fix
$(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');

 $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    $(this).tab('show');
    var scrollmem = $('body').scrollTop();
    window.location.hash = this.hash;
    $('html,body').scrollTop(scrollmem);
  });
});
```

And

```
 $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the hash part has to be appended last.
This link format won't work:

```
my-website.com/site.php#tab1?page=2
```

But this one should

```
my-website.com/site.php?page=2#tab1
```

Comment: Oh thanks for such a fast FIX! It works like charm :)

Comment: Now there is another issue... If i click on page 2 on tab1, then im switching to another tab, there is still ?page=2#tab2 and there is MySQL result wich is only on one page. I was trying to add ?page=1 to each tab link, but it wont work..